# React-Native Android and iOS emulators in Pycharm Professional Edition on Linux

Tags: pycharm, android-emulator, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to run a React-native app in Pycharm (on Linux) but I don't understand how to install Android and iOS emulators. I tried to follow the tutorial [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/react-native.html#ws_react_native_run_and_debug), but apparently it failed. When I try to launch on Android `react-native run-android` I get the following error :

```
react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/media/dev/test/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

The same way, when I try for iOS I get this error :

```
error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at /media/dev/test/ios/Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?
info Found Xcode project "reactNative_tests.xcodeproj"
error Could not get the simulator list from Xcode. Please open Xcode and try running project directly from there to resolve the remaining issues. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: spawnSync xcrun ENOENT
    at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1067:20)
```

So my question is simple : How to install these emulators in Pycharm ?

Comment: It looks like the steps for setup environment for react-native are not fully processed.

although we can try to open the project in android studio and Xcode so it will auto-configured as per the required configuration required to run the app

Comment: Thanks but I also tried and I didn't managed to make it work in Android studio as well, the following message appears when I opened the project :
`Cannot determine module type ("PYTHON_MODULE") for the following module:"untitled" The module will be treated as a Unknown module`